# Counting number of letters in a string

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

```
.data 
str: .ascii "aasembly language is fun./0"
.equ len, (. - str)
counta: .int 0
countb: .int 0
countc: .int 0
countA: .int 0
countB: .int 0
countC: .int 0
lowera: .ascii "a"
lowerb: .ascii "b"
lowerc: .ascii "c"
uppera: .ascii "A"
upperb: .ascii "B"
upperc: .ascii "C"

.text
.globl _start
_start:

lea str, %esi
mov $0, %ecx
mov lowera, %al
mov lowerb, %bl
mov lowerc, %cl
mov uppera, %dl
mov upperb, %ah
mov upperc, %bh
forloop:
cmpb (%esi), %al
je doescounta
cmpb (%esi), %bl
je doescountb 
cmpb (%esi), %cl
je doescountc
cmpb (%esi), %dl
je doescountA
cmpb (%esi), %ah
je doescountB
cmpb (%esi), %bh
jne dontcount

doescountC: 
incl countC
jmp dontcount
doescountb: 
incl countb
jmp dontcount
doescountc: 
incl countc
jmp dontcount
doescountA: 
incl countA
jmp dontcount
doescountB: 
incl countB
jmp dontcount
doescounta: 
incl counta

dontcount:
incl %ecx
add $1, %esi
cmp $len, %ecx
jna forloop
mov counta, %eax
mov countA, %ebx
mov $1, %eax
mov $0, %ebx
int $0x80
.end
```

I'm trying to count all the abc in the string. It only works for 3 counts. If I have more than 3 it will only scan the first letter of the string.

Comment: As a courtesy, if you see your post come out with broken formatting, click the [edit link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49583226/edit) and fix it by using the code formatting button on the toolbar. As to your problem, learn to use a debugger.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/unreadablecode/ http://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/ http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Comment: That doesn't look like NASM, that looks like GNU assembler (`as`) using AT&T syntax.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> mov $0, %ecx
>
> mov lowerc, %cl
> ```

You're using the `%ecx` register for 2 different things at the same time!

Because **the `%cl` register is just the lowest 8 bits of `%ecx`**, assigning *lowerc* to `%cl` destroys the resetted counter in `%ecx`.
Instead of starting at 0, the counter starts at 99 which is the ASCII code for the small caps "c".

> ```
> cmp $len, %ecx
> jna forloop
> ```

As a consequence the `jna forloop` will never jump back since `%ecx` already exceeds the immediate value that you compare it to.

A simple solution would be that instead of writing `mov lowerc, %cl`, you write `mov lowerc, %dh`.

Alternatively consider comparing with an immediate value:

```
cmpb $99, (%esi)   ;Compare with "c"
je doescountc
```